# How to define a UI so that the Buttons don't move when re-sizing the Window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want my buttons size not growing only stay on same location. Here two picture to illustrate:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?  You will get a better response if you post at least some attempted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do that in WPF. This is probably the simplest:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Button" Padding="20,5" Margin="10" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Button" Padding="20,5" Margin="10" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Button" Padding="20,5" Margin="10" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="Button" Padding="20,5" Margin="10" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's information about the different containers you can use in WPF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx

I'm presuming you do not want the behavior you see in the second screenshot. If you really want everything to stay in its same location (meaning resizing the window will not move the button), you could use a grid with hard coordinates for each item. However, as Sheridan pointed out, this is not a good idea. WPF includes fantastic support for layout of controls. In my development, I often use the grid with star sizing. One thought based on what you wrote:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

This would allow you to have controls placed at the top and bottom of your form, and would behave well when resized. (Again, it was unclear if this is what you wanted.) From here, you could take this further and have two columns, and have a button in each. From there, you could play with margins.

Comment: -1 That's terrible advice that you're giving there... you should [almost] *never* hard code coordinates in the UI. There's *always* a better way than that. I'll be happy to remove this down vote if you edit your answer and improve it.

Comment: +1 (or not -1) For coming back to improve your answer. It is appreciated by the community.

Comment: No problem. I haven't posted many answers yet so it was helpful to get an idea of what you (and others, probably) do and don't find helpful.

Comment: I think that if you had added the `Button`s to complete your answer, you *might* even have got a vote or two. If you're curious, it might be a good idea to look through the [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) section of the Help Center to get a better idea of what constitutes a reputable answer.